# OPAM init fails : remote file is not a valid line

Tags: macos, curl, ocaml, fish, opam

I'm trying to setup both OCaml and OPAM on my macOS machine with the fish shell ; I first installed them and their dependencies through Homebrew.
`ocaml` and `ocamlc` run as expected, the problem occurs when I try to initialise OPAM, here's what I get when I run `opam init --shell=fish --debug`:

```
=-=- Fetching repository information =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
00:00.259  REPOSITORY              update default(0 http https://opam.ocaml.org)
00:00.260  CURL                    pull-repo
00:00.260  SYSTEM                  error: File /Users/al1nk/.opam/repo/default/urls.txt does not exist
00:00.260  CURL                    Rebuilding urls.txt at /Users/al1nk/.opam/repo/default
00:00.260  FILE(file_attributes)   Wrote ~/.opam/repo/default/urls.txt in 0.000s
00:00.283  SYSTEM                  mkdir /var/folders/5b/7_p_56gn63x1fn7v8v6fzl9c0000gn/T/opam-20566-d2d111
Processing: [default: http]
Processing: [default: http]
00:03.276  SYSTEM                  rmdir /var/folders/5b/7_p_56gn63x1fn7v8v6fzl9c0000gn/T/opam-20566-d2d111
00:03.298  SYSTEM                  error: remote_file: '�}�r$����~��׺�;��l����p�8ju�)i�~�3�x�D��䙑D�{�2�@�;���߿�"ƅ�m�FF�#K�>7�u��yk���Ͽ�����]�*_�o��g����y��U���VL J�ac��Q!�!��o���$�^O4-��9 [�xu�)?��a1�eB0Iz�b=x�"�$�5��!VCt�BQ��6,~' is not a valid line.�:朓 �;=�.F����� �Nom��Dr.%* !��L��g�V��~<���g�y}_��
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Initialisation failed
# opam-version    1.2.2
# os              darwin
remote_file: '�}�r$����~��׺�;��l����p�8ju�)i�~�3�x�D��䙑D�{�2�@�;���߿�"ƅ�m�FF�#K�>7�u��yk���Ͽ�����]�*_�o��g����y��U���VL J�ac��Q!�!��o���$�cS���Z�9�L2�Ye�v�������-�Ņ ն썍C�b���iW^5M�^O4-��9 [�xu�)?��a1�eB0Iz�b=x�"�$�5��!VCt�BQ��6,~' is not a valid line.���g�y}_��
# opam-version    1.2.2
# os              darwin
remote_file: '�}�r$����~��׺�;��l����p�8ju�)i�~�3�x�D��䙑D�{�2�@�;���߿�"ƅ�m�FF�#K�>7�u��yk���Ͽ�����]�*_�o��g����y��U���VL J�ac��Q!�!��o���$�cS���Z�9�L2�Ye�v�������-�Ņ ն썍C�b���iW^5M�^O4-��9 [�xu�)?��a1�eB0Iz�b=x�"�$�5��!VCt�BQ��6,~' is not a valid line.
```

As it looks like the file being read is not properly decrypted, I tried again using another brewed version of curl, one where I reinstalled curl linking it with a brewed OpenSSL, also tried git instead of https (ran `opam init --shell=fish --kind=git --debug https://github.com/ocaml/opam`, which gives me this output :

```
=-=- Fetching repository information =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
00:00.299  REPOSITORY              update default(0 git https://github.com/ocaml/opam)
Processing: [default: git]
Processing: [default: git]
Processing: [default: git]
Processing: [default: git]
Processing: [default: git]
Processing: [default: git]
[default] https://github.com/ocaml/opam updated
00:19.853  REPOSITORY              Updating ~/.opam/repo/compiler-index ...

00:19.853  REPOSITORY              compiler-index
00:19.853  COMPILER                prefixes /Users/al1nk/.opam/repo/default/compilers
00:19.854  FILE(repo-index)        Wrote ~/.opam/repo/compiler-index in 0.000s
00:19.854  REPOSITORY              Updating ~/.opam/compilers/ ...

00:19.854  REPOSITORY              global-index: { system:eff11570a021d31b9aa061882afdd2a8 }
00:19.854  REPOSITORY              repo-index  : {}
00:19.854  REPOSITORY              updated-compilers: {}
00:19.854  REPOSITORY              new-compilers    : {}
00:19.854  REPOSITORY              deleted-compilers: {}
00:19.854  REPOSITORY              Updating ~/.opam/repo/package-index ...

00:19.854  REPOSITORY              package-index
00:19.854  PACKAGE                 prefixes /Users/al1nk/.opam/repo/default/packages
00:19.857  FILE(repo-index)        Wrote ~/.opam/repo/package-index in 0.000s
00:19.857  REPOSITORY              Updating ~/.opam/packages/ ...

00:19.857  REPOSITORY              new-packages     : {}
00:19.857  REPOSITORY              updated-packages : {}
00:19.857  REPOSITORY              changed-packages : {}
00:19.857  REPOSITORY              missing-installed: {}
00:19.857  REPOSITORY              deleted-packages: {}
00:19.857  REPOSITORY              packages-to-reinstall: {}
00:19.857  STATE                   add-to-reinstall all:true packages:{}
00:19.857  CLIENT                  updating package state
00:19.857  STATE                   install_compiler switch=system compiler=system
00:19.857  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/lib
00:19.857  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/lib/stublibs
00:19.858  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/lib/toplevel
00:19.858  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/build
00:19.858  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/bin
00:19.858  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/sbin
00:19.858  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/doc
00:19.859  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/man
00:19.859  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/install
00:19.859  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/man/man1
00:19.859  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/man/man1M
00:19.859  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/man/man2
00:19.859  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/man/man3
00:19.859  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/man/man4
00:19.859  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/man/man5
00:19.859  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/man/man6
00:19.860  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/man/man7
00:19.860  SYSTEM                  mkdir /Users/al1nk/.opam/system/man/man9
00:19.860  STATE                   install_global_config switch=system
00:19.860  FILE(.config)           Wrote ~/.opam/system/config/global-config.config in 0.000s
00:19.861  STATE                   add_switch switch=system compiler=system
00:19.863  CLIENT                  installing compiler packages
00:19.863  STATE                   LOAD-STATE(switch-install-with-packages-2)
00:19.864  STATE                   ROOT      : /Users/al1nk/.opam
00:19.864  STATE                   SWITCH    : system
00:19.864  STATE                   COMPILER  : system
00:19.864  STATE                   COMPILERS : { system }
00:19.864  STATE                   REPOS     : { default }
00:19.864  STATE                   PACKAGES  : {}
00:19.864  STATE                   INSTALLED : {}
00:19.864  STATE                   ROOTS     : {}
00:19.864  STATE                   REINSTALL : {}
00:19.864  STATE                   Creating a cache of metadata in ~/.opam/state.cache ...

00:19.865  STATE                   ~/.opam/state.cache written in 0.000s
00:19.865  STATE                   State switch-install-with-packages-2 loaded in 0.001s
[ERROR] Base package base-threads of compiler system not found! Ignored.
[ERROR] Base package base-bigarray of compiler system not found! Ignored.
[ERROR] Base package base-unix of compiler system not found! Ignored.
00:19.885  SOLVER                  resolve request=install:() remove:() upgrade:(base-threads & base-bigarray & base-unix)
00:19.885  SOLVER                  cudf_versions_map
00:19.885  SOLVER                  Load cudf universe (depopts:false, build:true)
00:19.885  CUDF                    resolve request=install:() remove:() upgrade:(base-bigarray & base-threads & base-unix) criteria:"-count(removed),-notuptodate(request),-sum(request,version-lag),-count(down),-notuptodate(changed),-count(changed),-notuptodate(solution),-sum(solution,version-lag)"
00:19.886  SOLVER                  Load cudf universe (depopts:false, build:true)
00:19.886  SOLVER                  Load cudf universe (depopts:true, build:false)
00:19.886  SOLVER                  Load cudf universe (depopts:true, build:true)
00:19.886  CUDF                    graph_of_actions root_actions={}
[ERROR] Inconsistent set of base compiler packages: {} needed but not included / { base-bigarray, base-threads, base-unix } extra
[ERROR] Initialisation failed
OpamGlobals.Exit(66)
```

)

Where could that come from ?

Answer (score 2):

This type of problem is typically caused by your *.config/fish/config.fish* running commands that write to stdout for non-interactive sessions. You need to ensure that all such commands are placed within a block of this form:

```
if status is-interactive
    echo Welcome, master
end
```

Comment: I have no such line in my config.fish, only managing my $PATH. I tried with an empty config.fish, I still get the same errors (with both https and git).

Comment: The https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Usage.html documentation shows uses of `eval $(opam something)`. Which won't work with fish unless `opam` has explicit support for fish.  Your invocation, `opam init --shell=fish`, implies that OPAM has support for fish. In which case I don't know what to tell you other than someone from the Ocaml community will probably have to provide an answer since my answer covers the only fish specific aspect of your issue.